# How to allow users to mount FUSE/exfat filesystems in fstab without root?

Tags: linux, mount, fuse, exfat

I have a filesystem listed in `/etc/fstab` and I'd like a normal user to be able to mount it.

Normally I would just add the `users` option and it will work, however it seems that if the filesystem is mounted by a FUSE helper, this doesn't work:

```
/dev/disk/by-label/SDCARD   /mnt/sdcard   exfat   x-gvfs-hide,users,noatime,fmask=0133,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,uid=1000,gid=985,noauto
```

Should a normal user try to mount this:

```
$ mount /mnt/sdcard/
FUSE exfat 1.4.0 (libfuse3)
ERROR: failed to open '/dev/sda1': Permission denied.
```

It seems that although the `users` option allows the `mount` command to run, it still only runs as a normal user and not as root.

I don't particularly want to give the normal user direct access to the device, and `sudo` will already solve the problem but I am trying to make this work without it.  The SD card is used in a device that requires exfat, so reformatting to FAT32 won't work.

Is there any way that will allow this to proceed as it does when using a non-FUSE filesystem, specifically that the device file has the same restrictions but a normal user can mount and unmount the device without root or sudo access?

Comment: does simply mounting things using `udisksctl mount -b /dev/disk/by-label/SDCARD` not work?

Comment: @MarcusMüller: That does work but it prompts for a password so no improvement over the other options unfortunately.

Comment: Not sure, but (ex)FAT does not support users/groups. You may use `gid=985,forecegid` .

Comment: @schweik ex(FAT) not supporting groups is why `uid=1000,gid=985` is present.  It causes all files to appear to be owned by 1000:985, so a normal user can access all the files (otherwise they are all owned by root).  There does not appear to be an option called `forcegid` so that is likely just ignored.

Comment: Well, I proposed the `forcegid` option because I use it while mounting `cifs`. I formated a flash-disk with exFAT, and mounted it using KDE automount as user (uid=1000). The `/proc/mounts` shows this options: `rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,iocharset=utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0`. Yes, there is no `forceguid`. Could it be helpfull?

Comment: @schweik: Well, those are the mount options I am already using :)